# Download local node to USB stick

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, full-node, blockchain-size

I want to download the blockchain so that I have independence from remote nodes. Because I want to use tails OS , I'd like to keep all data on the USB-Stick. ( booting live with persistence)

Can this be accomplished with a large USB-Stick, and decent write speed?
Current blockchain size is about 73GB. I just want to make sure this is possible, before I buy a USB stick with large capacity.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be accomplished with a large USB-Stick

Yes.

> ...and decent write speed?

Define "decent". USB 3.1 gen 2 is pretty fast. There are loads of USB drives on the market so you'll need to research carefully which you get.

> Current blockchain size is about 73GB...

No, it's more like ~90 GB unpruned and more like ~30 GB pruned. Hence you can focus your attention on speed rather than size. For example, 64 GB will be fine for the foreseeable future if you run a pruned node.